# XAML UWP Stackpanel size relative to screen size

Tags: xaml, uwp, pivot, uwp-xaml, stackpanel

I am building a UWP app that displays weather data. Currently I am working on a `dataTemplate` that is being used within a pivot

I am unable to get the Stackpanels width to size relative to the screen size (or their parent container) and unable to center them, I would also like to set a margin each side relative to the screen size (as I,ve done at ease before with html).

Also is it possible to have the image as a background to each stackpanel or display it beside the data as I am getting `Error: "The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once"`?

I have checked all the other posts available on this but cannot yet find a solution

```
<Page
x:Class="WeatherForecast.WeatherPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WeatherForecast"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListViewDataTemplate"  >

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="DeepSkyBlue" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding icon}" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="150" Margin="20" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Temperature: " ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding temp}"></TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Time : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding dtime}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Description : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Humidity : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding humidity}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Windspeed : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding windSpeed}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <TextBlock x:Name="cityBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"  ></TextBlock>
    <Button
        x:Name="ReturnToMain" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,10" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" FontSize="48" Background="#33B40C0C" BorderBrush="#FFF50B0B" FontFamily="Bauhaus 93" FontWeight="Bold" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Click to return to main" Click="ReturnToMain_Click" >Return To Main</Button>
    <Pivot x:Name="pvtWeather"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="100,100,100,100" Height="500" Background="LightBlue"  Foreground="LightPink"     >

    </Pivot>

</Grid>
```

```
    foreach (var day in myForecast.SortedDays)
        {
            var weathers = new ObservableCollection<WeatherController>();
            foreach (var weatherItem in day)
            {
                weathers.Add(weatherItem);
            }

            var pivotItem = new PivotItem
            {
                Header = myForecast.SortedDays[index++][0].dayOfWeek
            };
            ListView listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = weathers
            };
            pivotItem.Content = listView;
            listView.ItemTemplate = ListViewDataTemplate;
            pvtWeather.Items.Add(pivotItem);


        }
```

what i currently have 
[image]
What I am trying to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're relying a bit too much on only using a `StackPanel` for your layout.  If you want to do some relative sizing you'll either need to use a converter and some binding using helpers like the [FrameworkExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions) in the UWP Community Toolkit.

OR you could use grids a bit more to exploit their column sizing:

```
<Pivot>
        <PivotItem Header="Thursday">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="DeepSkyBlue" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="http://unsplash.it/g/100/150" Stretch="Fill" Height="100" Width="150" Margin="20" Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Temperature: " ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding temp}"></TextBlock>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Time : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dtime}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Description : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding desc}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Humidity : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding humidity}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Windspeed : " FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding windSpeed}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

The above example also puts the image to the side and has the middle area take up 80% of the pivot width.

It's a little hard to help more without more info about the list/pivot combo you have setup.

Comment: Thank you @Micheal . I have implemented this but this size of the bright blue boxes or data templates is still only relative to the size of text and image, may it be a issue with way i fill the pivots in C# . I updated the post to reflect this

Comment: @MidnightP could you maybe update the screenshot with what you have now and add another one of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have updated the post to show a rough idea of what i am trying to achieve